# dired-do-rename and last path in minibuffer

Tags: dired, minibuffer, history

When attempting to move a file in Dired using dired-do-rename, the prompt in the minibuffer currently defaults to the directory from which the files are being moved. It would be beneficial if Dired could remember the last directory used for copying or moving files and offer that as the default choice in subsequent operations. I am running Emacs 29.

Comment: What I do is open another dired buffer, the second one for the destination directory: copy/rename use that by default as the target directory. That requires that you customize `dired-dwim` and set it to `t`.

Comment: FWIW, the reasons for the default behavior are perhaps that it's expected that (1) if no file or subdir is targeted it's more likely that only the file name (not the dir part) be changed, and (2) when multiple files and subdirs are targeted it's likely that the target dir is close by the current dir (so you can more easily edit the default in the minibuffer). You may also want to make sure that option `insert-default-directory` is non-`nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @NickD. Using a second dired buffer as the destination and setting dired-dwim to `t` is a functional workaround. It offers a more visual approach to file management. However, I was hoping for a solution that would directly modify the `dired-do-rename` function to remember the last used directory, reducing the need for additional buffers.

Comment: @Drew, I will ensure that the `insert-default-directory option` is `non-nil`. However, my use case often involves moving files across different directories that are not necessarily close to each other. Hence, a modification to remember the last used directory would streamline my workflow significantly.